# Duplicate Articles appearing on website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have recently noticed on my website that a news page is repeating news articles from all "May"'s in the database (you will notice by looking here: [www.darlingtontowntwinning.co.uk/news_&_events](http://www.darlingtontowntwinning.co.uk/news_&_events))

I know that the coding is messy and possibly out of date, however, the website was built for us, and I don't have the skills (yet - I am learning!) to change the entire website at this time.

Is there a way to stop this from occuring - since I believe I have already got a limit of one of each record to display:

```
<div id="right" class="news">
<h3>Archive</h3>
<? $news=$session->getNews("","","",1);?>
<? while($article=mysql_fetch_array($news)){?>
<? 
$date = $article['thedate'];
$year = date('Y', $date);
$month = date('F', $date);
?>
<h4><?=$month." - ".$year;?></h4>
<nav class="small">
<? $innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);?>
<? while($innerarticle=mysql_fetch_array($innernews)){?>
<a href="/news/<?=$innerarticle['ftitle']?>" <? if($title==$innerarticle['ftitle']){?> class="active"<? }?>><?=$innerarticle['title']?></a>
<? }?>
</nav>
<? }?>
</div>
```

Get news function is:

```
function getNews($title,$month,$year,$group){
global $database;
return $database->getNews($title,$month,$year,$group);}
```

$database->getNews function is:

```
//get news
function getNews($title,$month,$year,$group){
   if($title){
       $q=$this->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." WHERE ftitle = '$title'" );
       return mysql_fetch_array($q);
   }else if($year && $month){
     $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%Y') = '$year') AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%M') = '$month') ORDER BY thedate DESC");
     return $q;
     }else if($group){
         $q=$this->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." GROUP BY (FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%Y')),(FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%M')) ORDER BY thedate DESC" );
       return $q;
     }else{
       $q=$this->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." ORDER BY thedate DESC" );
       return $q;
   }
```

}

Comment: It's showing "Planned Maintenance Notice - Webpage Unavailable." Can you please put the old code back up?

Comment: You need to show this function getNews  because without it we don't know what `$news=$session->getNews("","","",1);` does to select and return records

Comment: @dasfisch I was editing the website, back on now - sorry!

Comment: @popnoodles Got that function there (i think) for you

Comment: Could you post the $database->getNews() function as well? I think the query will help us debug better.

Comment: @dasfisch Yep I'll add it now :)

Comment: I know you didn't write it, that code is **really really very incredibly bad** please don't try to learn from it!

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be working

```
//get news from group 1

$news=$session->getNews("","","",1);

// for each article work out the date

while($article=mysql_fetch_array($news))
    $date = $article['thedate'];
    $year = date('Y', $date);
    $month = date('F', $date);
...

// then select everything again after working out the date (odd way of doing it)

$innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);

// and output each
```

So, because there are two event in May, it's outputting the header twice. Let me go over that...

- Get news grouped by date (allegedly)

  - June, just 1 article
  - 1:

    - Output the header
    - Select the articles
  - Output the article
  - May, 2 articles
  - 1:

    - Output the header
    - Select the articles
    - Output the article
  - 2:

    - Output the header
    - Select the articles
    - Output the article

This group by `SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." GROUP BY (FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%Y')),(FROM_UNIXTIME(thedate, '%M')) ORDER BY thedate DESC` is not behaving as expected and is returning two results for May

Try this code

```
<div id="right" class="news">
<h3>Archive</h3>
<? 
$news=$session->getNews();
$bydate=array(); // articles by date
while($article=mysql_fetch_array($news)){
    $k=date('YF', $date);
    if (!isset($bydate[$k])) $bydate[$k]=array(); // create sub array
    $bydate[$k][]=$article; // push article to this sub array
}
foreach ($bydate as $date->$articles){ // run through top array
    ?><h4><?= substr($date,4) . " - " . substr($date,0,4); ?></h4><nav class="small"><? 
    foreach ($articles as $innerarticle){ // now each article within this date
        ?><a href="/news/<?=$innerarticle['ftitle']?>" <? if($title==$innerarticle['ftitle']){?> class="active"<? }?>><?=$innerarticle['title']?></a><?
    }
    ?></nav><?
}
?></div>
```

and please change

```
function getNews($title,$month,$year,$group){
```

to

```
function getNews($title=NULL, $month=NULL, $year=NULL, $group=NULL){
```

Answer (score -2):

Welp. There's your problem.

Your function says, if($title). Since $title comes in as a required parameter in the function, I think PHP is registering it as, yes, that's a variable that is set. So, basically what happens, then, is you're getting back a mysql_fetch_array result, which you are then running mysql_fetch_array for a second time.

Try:

```
//in your function getNews()
if($title){
   $q=$this->query("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_NEWS." WHERE ftitle = '$title'" );
   return $q;
}
//rest of function down here
```

That could work. The issue I see is, doing that, you WILL CAUSE ISSUES ANYWHERE ELSE THAT FUNCTION IS CALLED. So be careful! The fix above is the fix to ensure you get code into a better state. If you want a hack, try this:

```
<? $innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);?>
<? foreach($innernews as $innerarticle) {?>
<a href="/news/<?=$innerarticle['ftitle']?>" <? if($title==$innerarticle['ftitle']){?> class="active"<? }?>><?=$innerarticle['title']?></a>
<? }?>
```

The foreach loop should give you what you want!

Comment: The script is asking for this `$innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);` $title isn't involved because `if ($title)` when `$title=""` returns false;

Comment: That's the only thing I could see that would give him doubles. I also think that since it's set as a required parameter in two functions, it's being passed in as a set variable with nothing in it. I don't know how else he wouldn't get an error? Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: What it's doing is passing an empty string  from one function to another, no amount of guessing is going to make that return anything but false. You are wrong to assume something might be different when code only ever behaves one way. *I think this might* when a comparison  has a definitive result is madness. You can't help someone by going on what you think PHP **might** do, especially when it takes seconds to find out what it **does** every time without deviation.

Comment: Well, since PHP is a pretty loose language, I have seen stranger things happen. So, I thought I'd try to give this guy some help. If it didn't solve his problem, maybe it helped him get closer to a real answer.

Comment: You have the wrong understanding of the term loose. Things can be written in many ways, empty is always going to return false. Try to help yes, but please don't speculate what PHP might return. There is nothing loose about that.

Comment: @popnoodles this doesn't seem to work :\ - nor the first solution either